# Powershell nested if / else command is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, vmware-tools

I am attempting to write a powershell script that removes VMware Tools off of physical workstations in my environment (don't ask) while ignoring VMs and I am having issues with the nested if / else statements in the "*#Execute VMware Tools removal if physical, then write log*" section of this code. Can anyone with more Powershell experience give me some pointers as to what I may have done wrong?

I receive the following error:

*else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.*

I apologize for the amateur formatting, I am still learning Powershell.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
#Create log path
$path = "D:\log\folder\location\"
If(!(test-path $path))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
#Gather required host info
$ComputerSystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -
ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop
switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Model) {
# Check for VMware Machine Type
   "VMware Virtual Platform" {
    $MachineType = "VM"
    }
# Otherwise it is a physical Box
    default {
    $MachineType = "Physical"
    }
    }
#Execute VMware Tools removal if physical, then write log
if($MachineType -eq "Physical") {
   $regpath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall"
   Get-childItem $regpath | % {$keypath = $_.pschildname 
   $key = Get-Itemproperty $regpath\$keypath}
  if($key.DisplayName -match "VMware Tools") 
   {$VMwareToolsGUID = $keypath} MsiExec.exe /x $VMwareToolsGUID /qn /norestart 
   {Write-output "VMware Tools Uninstalled" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Uninstalled.txt"}
  else
   {Write-output "VMware Tools Not Present" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Not_Present.txt"}
   } 
#Write output log if VM
if($MachineType -eq "VM")
 {Write-Output "Machine is virtual" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filePath 
 "D:\log\folder\location\Virtual_Machine.txt"}
else
 {Write-Output "Error" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath 
 "D:\log\folder\location\Error.txt"}
```

Comment: You're missing an opening `if` statement (the previous one was closed). Try using a more standard formatting, and it would jump right out at you.

Comment: Hi briantist, thank you for taking a look. To be honest I have no idea what a more standard formatting would be since everything I know, for now, is self taught (I am taking classes on PS in the fall). When you say the first *if* was closed do you mean the second *if* in the *#Execute VMware Tools removal if physical, then write log* section?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and made some edits for you so it looks cleaner and fixed your brackets (which was causing the error you are getting). Feel free to ask any questions! As a future reference, the easiest thing to do when you need to check if there is anything wrong with your script you can copy and paste it into PowerShell ISE and it will underline any errors it sees in red.

```
#Create log path
$path = "D:\log\folder\location"

If(!(test-path $path)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}

#Gather required host info
$ComputerSystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Model) {
    # Check for VMware Machine Type
    "VMware Virtual Platform" {
    $Global:MachineType = "VM"
    }
    # Otherwise it is a physical Box
    default {
    $Global:MachineType = "Physical"
    }
}

#Execute VMware Tools removal if physical, then write log
if($MachineType -eq "Physical") {
    $regpath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall"
    Get-childItem $regpath | % {$Global:keypath = $_.pschildname 
    $Global:key = Get-Itemproperty $regpath\$keypath}
}

if($key.DisplayName -match "VMware Tools"){
    $VMwareToolsGUID = $keypath 
    MsiExec.exe /x $VMwareToolsGUID /qn /norestart -wait
    Write-output "VMware Tools Uninstalled" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath 
    "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Uninstalled.txt"
}else{
    Write-output "VMware Tools Not Present" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath 
    "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Not_Present.txt"
}

#Write output log if VM
if($MachineType -eq "VM"){
    Write-Output "Machine is virtual" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filePath 
    "D:\log\folder\location\Virtual_Machine.txt"
}else{
    Write-Output "Error" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath 
    "D:\log\folder\location\Error.txt"
}
```

Comment: One thing I did notice, was the line where you have your $Env:COMPUTERNAME. That line is getting the computer name, but you aren't using it anywhere else in your script. So really that line can be deleted unless you plan on putting that information out somewhere!

Comment: Thanks for all of your assistance guys. I now have a better understanding of proper formatting. I made a few additional changes to the listed answer to get it to work in my environment, but those are just reordering the commands. Ill see if I can post it for anyone else that might need the same help.

Comment: Hi Corey, the line I am using is *$ComputerSystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop*.  In this case *$env:COMPUTERNAME* is getting me the system info that provides me with the *model*. This is used in the next line *switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Model) {*.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what was going on with that. When I copied and pasted your code it put them on two separate lines and I didn't notice it. Glad I could help though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final script I used if anyone ever needs it.

Thanks to Cory Etmund and briantist for the pointers, time, and knowledge.

```
#Create log path
$path = "D:\log\folder\location\"

If(!(test-path $path)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}

#Gather required host info
$ComputerSystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop

switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Model) {
    # Check for VMware Machine Type
    "VMware Virtual Platform" {
    $Global:MachineType = "VM"
}
    # Otherwise it is a physical Box
    default {
    $Global:MachineType = "Physical"
    }
}

#Write output log if VM
if($MachineType -eq "VM"){
    Write-Output "Machine is virtual" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filePath "D:\log\folder\location\Virtual_Machine.txt"
    exit
}

#Execute VMware Tools removal if physical, then write log
if($MachineType -eq "Physical") {
    $regpath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall"
    Get-childItem $regpath | % {$Global:keypath = $_.pschildname 
    $Global:key = Get-Itemproperty $regpath\$keypath}
}

if($key.DisplayName -match "VMware Tools"){
    $VMwareToolsGUID = $keypath 
    MsiExec.exe /x $VMwareToolsGUID /qn /norestart -wait
    Write-output "VMware Tools Uninstalled" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Uninstalled.txt"
}else{
    Write-output "VMware Tools Not Present" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "D:\log\folder\location\VMware_Not_Present.txt"
}
```